# How to make a 3D .STEP model for components?

Tags: cad, model, 3d

Any ideas? I'm really trying to make my own 3D components, I'v read something about solidworks but i havn't seen any tutorial about this topic until now...

Comment: Use a MOSFET with an SMPS and a Colpitz Oscillator. Oh wait.. this isn't an EE question....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with EE.

Comment: Library Expert Lite is free, and will not only help with foot prints bus can export .step files of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolidWorks is a 3D parametric modeling package. It costs a few thousand dollars (currently about $4K USD plus options plus annual subscription) and there are plenty of courses you can take, books you can buy and YouTube videos. Despite being quite user-friendly there is a significant learning curve.

There are also free programs out there and ones that have student versions or other accommodations for non-commercial word, but SolidWorks is a fairly solidly-placed industry standard for lower end PC-based modeling.

Most 3D CAD programs will allow you to export or save as a .STEP file format such as AP214, which EDA programs such as Altium can import.

Comment: I will confirm the steep learning curve, even with good built in tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Autocad [Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/students-teachers-educators) is a widely used 3D design program.  There is a free version, a large [support community](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fusion-360/ct-p/1234), and tons of [tutorials](http://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/) available.  It can [output in multiple formats.](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/fusion-360/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Export-format-options-for-Fusion-360.html)

Answer (score 0):

Download the STEP models from the manufacturers. A vast majority of them provide STEP models for free (sometimes they require registration, but that's no big deal).

If that fails, check sites like http://3dcontentcentral.com/ . They are a community of engineers who develop 3D models of parts, electronic components included.

Between these two options you'll cover about 95% of your components. Beyond that SolidWorks is a great tool (or cheaper/free tools like SolidEdge) to design 3D models that can be saved in STEP formats and added to your design.